# Cmake automatically defaults to gcc-5

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, g++

I was trying to compile amber tools using cmake. I am using ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS with the default gcc version gcc-5 and g++5, and amber tool requires at least gcc-6. I have installed gcc-8 and g++8 and specified it using the CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER. The cmake command used is the command below:

```
cmake $AMBER_PREFIX/amber22_src \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$AMBER_PREFIX/amber22 \
-DCOMPILER=GNU \
-DMPI=FALSE -DCUDA=TRUE -DINSTALL_TESTS=TRUE \
-DDOWNLOAD_MINICONDA=TRUE \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-8 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-8 \
```

Even though the gcc g++ is specified I get the following error:

```
-- Starting configuration of Amber version 22.0.0...
-- CMake Version: 3.14.0
-- For how to use this build system, please read this wiki:
--     http://ambermd.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CMake
-- For a list of important CMake variables, check here:
--     http://ambermd.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CMake-Common-Options
-- **************************************************************************
-- Setting C compiler to gcc
-- Setting CXX compiler to g++
-- Setting Fortran compiler to gfortran
-- Amber source not found, only building AmberTools
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran  -- works
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether /usr/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /usr/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90 -- yes
-- 
************************************************************
Error: Amber requires at least g++-6.0
See https://ambermd.org/Installation.php for more info
************************************************************
-- 
CMake Error at cmake/VerifyCompilerConfig.cmake:30 (message):
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/AmberBuildSystem2ndInit.cmake:30 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:111 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/media/gpu-1/GPU_1_2TB/Ambertools22/amber22_src/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted.
Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables.
The following variables have changed:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER= /usr/bin/gcc-8
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= /usr/bin/g++-8

-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    DOWNLOAD_MINICONDA
    MPI


-- Build files have been written to: /media/gpu-1/GPU_1_2TB/Ambertools22/amber22_src/build

If the cmake build report looks OK, you should now do the following:

    make install
    source /media/gpu-1/GPU_1_2TB/Ambertools22/amber22/amber.sh
```

Thank you

Comment: uff, do you have a particular reason to stick with Ubuntu 16.04? That's positively ancient by now, and unless you're paying for the extended service, practically unmaintained. You seem to have installed a more modern CMake on that, because there was no Cmake 3.14 in UBuntu16.04. So, now you have a wild mixture of compilers and build tools. Easiest solution that doesn't cause *more* problems down the road is clean-slate switching to a modern Ubuntu, honestly.

Comment: Have you already configured with the default (version 5) GCC, and then run CMake again with the new compiler settings? Remove the CMake build directory with all its caches, and run the `cmake` command to create everything fresh.

Comment: Yea. I need cuda < 11 for this thing to run and my other PCs have cuda 11.7. I cannot change cuda as I have other software depending on it

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried that. Still no luck.

Comment: That's not a great argument, Cuda10 is available for at the very least Ubuntu 18.04 https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.2-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804 ; Also, try building your software in a Ubuntu 18.04 container, at least.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No no, please dont get me wrong, I dont want to change the cuda version as other people are using the PCs currently

Comment: yes, but you can keep the cuda version, but get a newer Ubuntu, which solves your ancient compilers/cmake/obsolescence problem, and because containers are a thing, you don't even have to set up a new operating system.

Comment: `-D <cache var>=<value>` is an option that goes before the source directory, see the first usage option here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html Personally I prefer specifying source and build dir via `-S` and `-B` though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not call it a problem of CMake, rather on the way Amber performs the control of the compiler through CMake, which most likely is performed by taking the first compiler that appears from the environment variable $PATH.

If you would like to compile it anyway, I can suggest two cheap ways:

- using the `update-alternatives` package, to change the "system
  default" gcc and g++
- prepend a path in PATH with `export PATH=absolute/path/to/a/folder:$PATH`, and in this path put two symbolic links called gcc and g++, that points at
  gcc-8 and g++-8

Comment: "I would not call it a problem of CMake". But it is, CMake auto-detects the `C` and `CXX` compiler unless you specify it via the used toolchain file. Using `update-alternatives` is not an ideal solution if you wish to use different versions of a given compiler for different projects (due to for example unspecified requirements). The symbolic link is an overkill and these practices lead to very badly kept projects. It's better to spend 10 minutes learning about CMake than to do "hacks" like these. You will end up like my ex-employer that required special `set-env.sh` scripts.

Comment: Indeed setting the environment variables `C` and `CXX` would be preferrable, CMake makes use of them, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-env-variables.7.html?highlight=environment#environment-variables-for-languages I'd prefer a toolchain file though, but this may not be possible with the given build process of the OP...

Answer (score 0):

According to this, you are still using existing cache files that you've generated before you set the new `C` and `CXX` compiler.

```
You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted.
Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables.
The following variables have changed:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER= /usr/bin/gcc-8
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= /usr/bin/g++-8
```

Based on `cmake $AMBER_PREFIX/amber22_src` you are running this from your build folder. In general I recommend using the syntax `cmake -S[source] -B[build]`. Your current working directory should be completely deleted. Once you do that, re-run your `cmake` command and it should be correctly set.

If it doesn't work you can do a sanity check by adding

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER [path_to_C])
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER [path_to_CXX])
```

**BE SURE TO PUT IT AT THE START OF THE CMAKELISTS FILE** i.e. before any `project()` line.

EDIT: Also have you heard about docker? It's a great tool for creating special contained environments for using legacy tools.

Comment: Those 2 `set` commands should be kept out of all `CMakeLists.txt` file. They should go into a toolchain file. The reason for this is that adding logic like this to a `CMakeLists.txt` file prevents reuse with other compilers and reuse as part of a bigger project via `add_subdirectory`.

Comment: I do agree with you here @fabian however I'm just answering the question here.